# JS canvas stretching div unintentionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have a div which holds an image. The image itself is loaded in later :

**HTML** :

```
<div id="image_holder" class='hide'>
    <img id="image" onload="createStimuli() " >
    <canvas id="canvasOverImage" class="coveringCanvas" ></canvas>
</div>
```

coveringCanvas style :

**CSS**:

```
.coveringCanvas { 
    position:relative;
    z-index:2 
}
```

Next, when the time is right I load in the image.

```
document.getElementById('image').src = `imagesource`;
```

Because now the image is loaded, it triggers `createStimuli()`:

```
function createStimuli() {
    var image = $('#image');        
    var canvas = $('#canvasOverImage');
    canvas.css({top:`-${image.height()}px`});   // set style via css
    canvas.attr({ "height":image.height(), "width" :image.width()});  // set attr in html
}
```

This code places the canvas exactly on top of the image (as intended) But it appears that before the position is changed to be on top, it is placed below or next to the image, stretching the canvas.

As a result, even though the canvas is on the image, the creation of the canvas stretches the div leaving empty space below/next to the div.

Is there a way to counter this? Or should i just resize the div after creating the canvas?

Comment: waht you to have exactly as final result ?

Comment: Sorry? You mean, what do i want as final result? That the creation of canvas does not influence the div height or width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work around this issue :

First set your `image_holder` div's `position` to `relative` . to make sure all absolute positionned elemnt will be positioning to this last .

Then make canvas `position` to `absolute` and `left` postion to `0`

```
#canvasOverImage {
  position:absolute;
}
```

You can test below snippet i've added some borders to canva to see result

```js
document.getElementById('image').src = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg";

function createStimuli() {
    var image = $('#image');        
    var canvas = $('#canvasOverImage');
    //canvas.css({top:-(image.height()+5)+'px'});   // set style via css
    canvas.attr({ "height":image.height(),"width" :image.width()});
}
```

```css
#image_holder {
  position:relative;
}

#canvasOverImage {
  border:1px solid red;
  position:absolute;
}

 #canvasOverImage {
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image_holder" class='hide'>
    <img id="image" onload="createStimuli() " ><!--
    --><canvas id="canvasOverImage" class="coveringCanvas" ></canvas>
</div>
```

Note that i've just remove 5 px to fit exactely image and remove extra space between image and canvas

Comment: Thanks for the input. I forgot to mention that the coveringCanvas class has postion set to relative, so that's not it unfortunately. I've added it to the main post.

Comment: Now i've understand your issue please , see my updated answer !

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish such thing in a more efficient manner by doing it using the following way ...

```js
document.getElementById('image').src = "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/52/30/66/523066972863437c1a5daa774d1e5414.jpg";

function createStimuli(e) {
    var canvas = $('#canvasOverImage')[0];
    // set canvas css style
    canvas.style.marginLeft = -(e.width + 3) + 'px'; // 3 ~ border width
    // set canvas attr in html
    canvas.width = e.width;
    canvas.height = e.height;
    // draw text on canvas *proves canvas is on top*
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.font = 'bold 18px Arial';
    ctx.fillText('hello', 10, 25);
}
```

```css
.coveringCanvas {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.hide {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image_holder" class='hide'>
    <img id="image" onload="createStimuli(this)">
    <canvas id="canvasOverImage" class="coveringCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```